# Graphics with MikTex

Tags: pstricks

I'm intent on doing some freelance work.  I use LaTeX in my primary job.  It's on a Linux platform maintained by others.  I've gotten a few requests which I cannot honor at my primary job, but doing the work on my own is not verboten.

I've downloaded MikTeX onto my PC / Windows10 at home.  My first job includes making a graph.  X and Y coordinates >0  Each unit has a horizontal or vertical line extending the entire dimension of the square graph.  I.e. a bunch of squares.  At the intersections are circles.

My training did not include this kind of graphic work, only text.  Can anyone point me in the right direction to get started making these simple figures?  I have acquired a LaTeX Graphic Companion book, but it's dated 1997.  The first code I copied from the text choked on `\usepackage{pstcol}`.  The error message indicated it was an obsolete term and suggested `pstricks`, which I used. But I cannot seem to get anything on the `.pdf` page.

When I posted this question on another LaTeX site, they immediately tried to sell me something.

I the preamble I'm declaring `\usepackage{pstricks}`

```
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(2,2)\showgrid
\psline[linewidth=1pt,linecolor=gray] 
{<->}(0.5,0)(0,1)(1,1.5)(1.5,1)(.5,.5)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Gets me an error message

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.96 \begin{pspicture}(0,0)(2,2)\showgrid

?
```

Commenting out the `\showgrid` with % gets me the following.

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\c@lor@to@ps ->\PSTricks 
                         _Not_Configured_For_This_Format
l.98 {<->}
          (0.5,0)(0,1)(1,1.5)(1.5,1)(.5,.5)
?
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

I can do the text, but the graphics befuddle me.

Comment: Search on pgfplots

Comment: You should compile with latex > dvips > ps2pdf. Did you? Or did you compile with pdflatex?

Comment: This is a new environment for me, coming linux, so bear with me.  I clicked TypeSet, then .pdflatex.  I'm not finding ps2pdf.

Comment: "Search on pgfplots" - Scott Seidman..  I'm not sure what to do with this information. Search where?

Comment: run the document with `xelatex`

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

I think `pstricks` is easier to learn because it uses a LaTeX-like syntax – actually it's a LaTeX interface to Adobe Postscript.

There is a difficulty when using it: for quite some time, people have been compiling with `pdflatex` to obtain directly a .pdf document from .tex source file. However, `pdflatex` has no computation engine  to perform the computations required by Postscript. That is why you have this error message. So  you have three possibilities:

- Compile along the classic chain `latex -> dvips -> pstopdf`;
- Compile with `pdflatex`, and delegate the compilation to an external program, loading the `auto-pst-pdf` package *after* `pstricks. This will extract the pstricks code to a temporary file,    produce a  (cropped) pdf graphic file from an auxiliary compilation, and incorporate this image file to your main document.
- Compile with  `xelatex`.

Here is your code, slightly modified, to show a little more of the syntax. It has to be compiled with `pdflatex`.  If you want to follow one of the two other ways, just remove (or comment) `\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}`.

One more word: for the auxiliary compilation to work, you have to add the switch `--enable-write18` to `pdflatex`. This is done  from your editor configuration.

```
\documentclass[border=3pt, svgnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add,}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf} 

\begin{document} 

\psset{arrowinset=0.15, linejoin=1,}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](0,0)(2,2)
 \psline[linewidth=1pt,linecolor=SteelBlue] {<->}(0.5,0)(0,1)(1,1.5)(1.5,1)(.5,.5)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

To configure pdflatex in TeXworks, you have to fo to the `Edit -> Preferences` menu, click on the `Typesetting` tab, select the `pdflatex`line, and click on the `Edi` button. Your configuration for `pdflatex` should be something like this:

[image]

Comment: I copied and pasted your code.  Now it is trying to compile, adding packages along the way.  Looks like we be on to something

Comment: Okay, now i have a warning message about an escaped turtle:  
Package ifplatform Warning: 
    shell escape is disabled, so I can only detect \ifwindows.

)

! Package auto-pst-pdf Error: 
    "shell escape" (or "write18") is not enabled:
    auto-pst-pdf will not work!
.

See the auto-pst-pdf package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.134         Or turn off auto-pst-pdf.}
                                        %
?

Comment: You have to add the switch from your editor. Which one do you use?

Comment: I'm editing int TeXworks

Comment: You do type in an editor. TeXworks? TeXmaker? TeXstudio?

Comment: I mis-read your previous post.  I'm in TeXworks

Comment: OK. I'll add a screenshot of my configuration and some explanations.

Comment: stackexchange wants me to move this discussion to: "automatically move this discussion to chat?"  Should I click it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66312/discussion-between-bernard-and-tommyk).